# Convert Hex to String using VbScript

Tags: vbscript

here is a script which convert string into hex code:

```
strString = "test"
strHex =""
For i=1 To Len(strString)
    strHex = strHex & " "  & Hex(Asc(Mid(strString,i,1)))
Next

strHex = Right(strHex,Len(strHex)-1)

WScript.Echo strHex
```

I want to do a reverse action which converts hex into string, is this possible using vbscript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VBScript uses "&H" to mark numbers as hexadecimals. So

```
>> WScript.Echo Chr("&H" & "41")
>>
A
>>
```

demonstrates the strategy in principle. Demo code:

```
Option Explicit

Function s2a(s)
  ReDim a(Len(s) - 1)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = Mid(s, i + 1, 1)
  Next
  s2a = a
End Function

Function s2h(s)
  Dim a : a = s2a(s)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = Right(00 & Hex(Asc(a(i))), 2)
  Next
  s2h = Join(a)
End Function

Function h2s(h)
  Dim a : a = Split(h)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = Chr("&H" & a(i))
  Next
  h2s = Join(a, "")
End Function

Dim s : s = "test"
WScript.Echo 0, s
WScript.Echo 1, s2h(s)
WScript.Echo 2, h2s(s2h(s))
```

output:

```
0 test
1 74 65 73 74
2 test
```

**Update wrt comment/unicode:**

Use [AscW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfw01fx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)/[ChrW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws6aa3sf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) ([VB ref](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145745/en-us)) to deal with UTF 16.

```
Option Explicit

Function s2a(s)
  ReDim a(Len(s) - 1)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = Mid(s, i + 1, 1)
  Next
  s2a = a
End Function

Function s2h(s)
  Dim a : a = s2a(s)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = Right("0000" & Hex(AscW(a(i))), 4)
  Next
  s2h = Join(a)
End Function

Function h2s(h)
  Dim a : a = Split(h)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = ChrW("&H" & a(i))
  Next
  h2s = Join(a, "")
End Function

Dim s : s = "abcä" & ChrW("&H" & "d98a")
WScript.Echo 0, s
WScript.Echo 1, s2h(s)
WScript.Echo 2, h2s(s2h(s))
```

Comment: But there is a problem, it can not convert unicode characters, go to this site http://hex.online-toolz.com/tools/text-hex-convertor.php and try to convert (d98a) from hex into string, it will work but in vbscript it is not working :(

Comment: @Stranger - please see update and mark fix of error in the ASCII version.

Comment: thanks for update, but still there is a problem, it will show unreadable characters as Unicode chars. is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Stranger - please publish detailed description/representative sample of your input data.

Comment: @Stranger - can you rule out that the result just reflects the incapability of the output device (console, msgbox, ...) to *display* those characters? Did you *compare* `h2s(s2h(s))` against `s`?

Comment: it seems it does not depend on output device, if you try to show "حمید" using echo it works fine, but if you try to convert it into hex then turn in it back into Unicode you will get unreadable chars :(

Comment: @Stranger - (1) maybe your display uses UTF-8; the script definitely uses UTF-16 (2) publish a complete/short script and your device config (chcp, font selected) demonstrating the problem

Comment: can you show me the output of h2s(s2h(s)) with a picture plz?