# Hex string compress

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, compression, hex

i have a code which encrypt and decrypt string with secret key

```
<%
Dim a, string, key
string = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОП РСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯZàáâ{'-+/}äãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð~!@#$%^"

key = "CaIm^0=SGQWp1aL"
a = s2h(string,key)

response.write(a)
response.write(h2s(a,key))

Function s2a(s)
  ReDim a(Len(s) - 1)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = Mid(s, i + 1, 1)
  Next
  s2a = a
End Function

Function s2h(s,k)
  Dim a : a = s2a(s)
  Dim i,y
  y=1

  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = Right("0000" & Hex(AscW(a(i))+AscW(Mid(k,y,1))), 4)
      y=y+1
      if y > len(k) then y=1

  Next
  s2h = Join(a)
End Function

Function h2s(h,kk)
  Dim a : a = Split(h)
  Dim i,yy
  yy=1
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = ChrW(("&H" & a(i))-AscW(Mid(kk,yy,1)))
      yy=yy+1
      if yy > len(kk) then yy=1
  Next
  h2s = Join(a, "")
End Function


%>
```

But i get a big hex string

> 0453 0472 045B 0480 0472 0445 043E 0469 045E 0469 0470 048A 044C 047D
>   0469 0461 0480 0069 048D 047F 0452 0460 0477 046C 0477 047E 0498 045A
>   048B 0477 046F 048E 0477 049C 00B8 0110 011E 0135 00C2 0078 0084 009B
>   0060 00DE 0130 0126 0146 014E 017A 0165 0149 0125 013C 0131 013C 016E
>   019F 011D 014E 013A 0132 01A3 018D 015F 0151 0124 0133 0148 013F 014A
>   0151 016B 012D 01D4 01B7 0142 015E 01C5 01E7 014F 0117 014A 01B4 01C5
>   0111 0118 0132 00F5 0124 0111 0147 0167 0155 0183 0176 00F8 0106 011D
>   0112 011D 0124 013E 0100 018F 018D 0186 0133 011C 0141 0134 0105 0115
>   012C 0121 012C 0133 01E2 019B 01D9 0129 01BE 01DA 011A 014C 0125 0182
>   0103 015F 01A7 01CE 2259 0160 00AF 0082 008C 0066 0085 006E 00CB

or without spaces

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

How i can compress it, i want a shortest hexoutput string

Comment: try using ASCII encrypt decrypt method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `h2s` needs to break the input string into reasonable parts. As done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342839/603855) and in your code, Split() - on space - is used. In that case you can go without the zero padding

```
Right("0000" & Hex(AscW(a(i))+AscW(Mid(k,y,1))), 4)
```

in `s2h`. Alternatively, you can keep the padding and use `s2h = Join(a, "")` in `s2h` to get a string of 4 hex-digit chunks without space; `h2s` then
can't use Split(), but someting like

```
Function h2s(h)
  ReDim a((Len(h) \ 4) - 1)
  Dim p : p = 1
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      WScript.Echo Mid(h,p,4)
      a(i) = ChrW("&H" & Mid(h,p,4))
      p = p + 4
  Next
  h2s = Join(a, "")
End Function
```